# Address family not supported by protocol in connect()

Tags: c, sockets, unix

Following code is a socket programming sample for TCP client.

But when I run this, connect() is retuned as Address family not supported by protocol.
i am trying for a server client communication via sockets.
First we send some strings to the client,Then we read some strings from the client and print them out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/un.h>
#define ADDRESS     "mysocket"
char *str[3]={"dfgff","trer","ytt"};
int main()
{
char c;
FILE *fp;
register int i,s,ns,len;
int fromlen;
struct sockaddr saun,fsaun;
if((s=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
perror("server:socket");
exit(1);
}


  unlink("mysocket");

    if (bind(s,&saun,sizeof(saun))<0)
    {
        perror("server: bind");
        exit(1);
    }
if (listen(s, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((ns = accept(s, &fsaun, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: accept");
        exit(1);
    }
 fdopen(ns, "r");

    /*
     * First we send some strings to the client.

    for (i = 0; i <3 ; i++)
        send(ns, str[i], strlen(str[i]), 0);

    /*
     * Then we read some strings from the client and
     * print them out.
     */
    for (i = 0; i <3; i++)
    {
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
            putchar(c);

            if (c == '\n')
                break;
        }
    }
close(s);
exit(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your code, as you don't initialize structures before you use them (prime example: you use `saun` when it's not initialized in the call to `bind`). There are more such problems.

Comment: I do not see any call to `connect()`. The code shown looks like server code, not like a client.

Comment: OT: `c` should be declared as `int` not as `char`.

Comment: This looks like a server code. Where is `connect`? In fact you've everything of `bind`, `listen` and `accept`.